# Ionic 2 menuToggle on previous page is always triggered when back button is tapped

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

When I press the back button on any page that takes you back to a page where a menuToggle is on the left, the menuToggle will trigger as if when I press the back button, it presses through all the layers and taps the menuToggle as well.

```
// CHILD PAGE
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons start>
            <button (tap)="goBackPage()" ion-button icon-only clear end color="light" class="">
               <ion-icon class="cpa-header-btn-icon" name="ios-arrow-round-back"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title color="light" ion-text>{{title}}</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

// PREVIOUS/PARENT PAGE
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar no-border>
        <ion-buttons start>
            <button menuToggle menuToggle="left" ion-button icon-only clear>
                <ion-icon ion-text color="light" name="menu"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>My Wallet</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: Maybe has to do with tap vs click event? what happens if you bind the click event as well?

Comment: Changing tap to click doesn't fix it

Comment: Im guessing you use the nav service that is typically used to add to the history stack? usually something like `this.nav.push(newpage)`?

Comment: Yes. In most cases my goBackPage() functions will just pop(), but sometimes I setRoot. Either way, the same behavior occurs.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious from the html provided. Can you should more code or offer more context? What platform is this on(web ios android)? Happens with all components? The more the merrier

Comment: The code is irrelevant. It happens regardless of whether I use (tap) or navPop. It is intermittent. And happens on iOS because the menuToggle attribute is "behind" the back button.

Comment: It happens when you call nav.pop even if you never clicked anything?

Comment: Nope. navPop the attribute

Comment: Quick and dirty would be to stopPropagation() but otherwise that may be a bug. You could also do some clean up in the destructor of the previous page to ensure its gone or hidden but thats not ideal.